# Simple Regex find and replace in a php file using notepad++

Tags: regex

I've got a really large array that i need to replace some stuffs in it ( using notepad++ regular expression `search and replace` ) but i don't the right `Regex` for it , and everything i tried failed.

Example :

```
'label' => 'Some text',
```

Must be replaced with :

```
'label' => __('Some text', 'mytextdomain'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the Regular Expression radio button is clicked on the Search Mode panel of the Replace dialog.  Then

Find what:    `('[^']*') => ('[^']*')`
Replace with: `\1 => __\(\2, 'mytextdomain'\)`

The main thing is that if you want parenthesis in your result they need to be escaped because parenthesis are special just like `^` `&` `.` `+` and `*`